# I need my Python code to be simpler and more professional

Tags: python, list, loops

I have written a function in Python which includes a loop and some conditional statements. I would like to know how I can simplify the code.

The program is supposed to do the following:

Write a function called "middle" that takes a list and returns a new list that contains all but the first and last elements.

I am using an "if" statement and three "elif" statements where two of these "elif" statements have two lines of code repeated. The program works perfectly. But, I have a sense that it can be written in a more professional (i.e., elegant and shorter) way.

```
def middle():
    i=0
    list=[]   #an empty list
    while True:
        entry=input("Enter the list memeber:  ")
        if entry !="done":
            list.append(entry)
            i=i+1
        elif i==0:
            print("Your list is empty :(!")
            exit()
        elif i==1:
            del list[0]
            print("The remaining list is:  ", list)
            exit()
        elif i>=2:
            del list[0]
            del list[-1]
            print("The remaining list is:  ", list)
            exit()
middle()
```

Comment: Just use `my_list[1:-1]`

Comment: Also, avoid naming you list `list`, as this is a Python builtin function.

Comment: Note, your function does not take a list as an argument, it doesn't take any arguments at all... It also doesn't return a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the list:

```
def middle(sample_list):
    sample_list = sample_list[1:-1] # Starting from the second element until one before the last
    print(sample_list) # Print out the list
    return sample_list
middle([5,6,4,3,1]) # Call middle with list as an argument
```

Output:

```
[6, 4, 3]
```

Here is an [excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) on slicing and slice notation to help you understand it further.

Comment: This function does not return a `list`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Edited, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: So, slicing of the first and the last element works irrespective of the length of the list. But, poping a list element requires a specific position of the elements.

Comment: @Navid Popping a list element does not require a specific position of the elements if you're using data structure types such as Queues, Stacks, deques, any FIFO or LIFO data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing, for example:

```
if len(array) > 1:
    array = array[1:-1]
    print("Remaining list is :", array)

else:
    print("Your list is too small")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by

a=[1,2,3,4,5]

b=a[1:-1]

print(b)